# How to skip Directory or file when UnauthorizedAccessException occurs

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Code is below. I am trying to fetch files from a specific path as `sDirPath` and then store in a tree view, basically making a custom folder browser dialog box. But the issue is, when I get system files or folders which are inaccessible, I get `UnauthorizedAccessException`. It occurs on folders or files like hidden and system folders or files e.g $recyle.bin in C:\ or shortcut of Documents and Settings. I just want to skip these folders or files. I don't want to fetch them.

```
Dim sAllfiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sDirPath, "*.*")
For Each sfile As String In sAllfiles          
    Dim objFileInformation As FileInfo = New FileInfo(sfile)
    Dim tnTreeNodeSub As TreeNode
    tnTreeNodeSub=tnTreeNodeRootDirectory.Nodes.Add(objFileInformation.Name)
Next
```

Comment: a try-catch inside the for each should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Try .. Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) statements are for exactly this.

For example, this will only ignore an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. Any other exception will still kill the loop.

```
Dim sAllfiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sDirPath, "*.*")
For Each sfile As String In sAllfiles
    Try
        Dim objFileInformation As FileInfo = New FileInfo(sfile)
        Dim tnTreeNodeSub As TreeNode
        tnTreeNodeSub=tnTreeNodeRootDirectory.Nodes.Add(objFileInformation.Name)
    Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
        Continue For 'Ignore the exception and move on
    End Try
Next
```

Comment: let me check again... as i have applied this before but it closes my app when breaking the loop

Comment: Note that with `Option Infer On` most of the `As String` etc. can be left out.

Answer (score -1):

Modification to Gabriel Luci's answer:

```
Try
    Dim sAllfiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sDirPath, "*.*")
    For Each sfile As String In sAllfiles
        Try
            Dim objFileInformation As FileInfo = New FileInfo(sfile)
            Dim tnTreeNodeSub As TreeNode
            tnTreeNodeSub=tnTreeNodeRootDirectory.Nodes.Add(objFileInformation.Name)
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            Continue For 'Ignore the exception and move on
        End Try
    Next
Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
    'Ignore the exception and move on
End Try
```

As this doing like this and adding one more catch will help if you give inaccessible path in sDirPath directly if you dont add it will close you application.

Comment: But you are catching the same exception. That will not catch a non-existent path. Also, please indent your code appropriately to make it more readable.